# Django : URL is not serving the correct page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Im learning django and in my apps, I have a **urls.py** which has **2 urlpatterns** in it.  **No matter** what ever url I use in browser, it **redirects to first url** only

**My urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact')
]
```

**my views.py**

```
def index(request):
    title = 'welcome'
    form = SignupForm(request.POST or None)
    context={'title':title,'form':form}
    if form.is_valid():
        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        email= form.cleaned_data['email']
        email_save,created=Signup.objects.get_or_create(email=email)

    return render(request,'index.html',context)

def contact(request):
    contact_info=ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if contact_info.is_valid():
        contact_info.save(commit=False)
        print contact_info.cleaned_data['name']

    return render(request,'contact.html',{'contact_info':contact_info})
```

**My form**

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Signup
        fields = ['fullname','email']

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=128, required=True,)
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)
    phone=forms.IntegerField(max_value=10)
    message=forms.TextInput()
```

as per my ***contact url*** it should give me ***contact.html***, but it renders only ***index.html*** 
[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: change the first redirection line to `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),`

Comment: Thanks .......It works fine now.........cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the first redirection line to

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
```

because contact page url pattern contains  `^` (url pattern of index page ) which redirects you to the index page. If you change like above, `index` page should be shown only when the url string is followed by an empty string.